# working with span and div to get 2 rows text beside a icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am working divs and spans to achieve UI as I shown in the image. I am struck with css properties. How can I achieve this with css

[image: Desired view]

this is the sample html

```css
.row .logo {float:left;}
.row .venue {float:right;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="logo">
O
<span class="a">
zeee
</span>
<span class="b">
2017
</span>
</div>

<div class="venue">
<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="a">
MyDate
</span>
<span class="b">
MyLocation
</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The above code doesn't actually show us any attempt you've made to achieve your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use boostrap 4 and enjoy the flex properties :

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#justify-content

> **Justify content**
>
> Use justify-content utilities on flexbox containers to change the alignment of flex items on the main axis (the x-axis to start, y-axis if flex-direction: column). Choose from start (browser default), end, center, between, or around.

You can update your class name and turn `<div class=" row">` into `<div class=" d-flex justify-content-between">`

```css
/* demo purpose only */
.logo {
  color: green;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.logo :first-child {
  font-size: .65em;
  color: purple;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.logo :last-child {
  font-size: 0.35em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class=" d-flex justify-content-between">
  <div class="logo">
    O
    <span class="a">
zeee
</span>
    <span class="b">
2017
</span>
  </div>

  <div class="venue">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="a">
MyDate
</span>
    <span class="b">
MyLocation
</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

[codepen and flex to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mwYeVM)

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```css
.row .logo {
  float: left;
}

.row .venue {
  float: right;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 36px !important;
}

#calender {
  float: left;
}

#text {
  float: right;
}

#o {
  font-size: 64px !important;
  color: #07b512;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}

#zee {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  color: #3b1670;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 40%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

#year {
  display: flex;
  width: 25px;
  color: #8e1b30;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.a,.b{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="logo">
    <div id="o">
      O
    </div>
    <div id="zee" class="a">
      zeee
    </div>
    <div id="year" class="b">
      2017
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="venue">
    <div id="calender">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
      <div class="a">
        MyDate
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        MyLocation
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```